# I might have accidentally merged 2 accounts. Could this cause problems?

Tags: support

I'm not sure the exact process that led to this. I previously had stack overflow accounts: 1 associated with my work gmail account, and one associated with my home gmail account. I didn't have much activity using my home account, and I actually want to only have one stack overflow account, so I decided to use my home gmail to log in to my "work" stack overflow account. Of course stack overflow didn't let me use my home gmail account because I was already using it, so I decided to delete my "home" stack overflow account. I followed the process to delete it. Then I thought: while I'm waiting for this account to be deleted, let me remove my home gmail log-in credentials from my home stack overflow account (substituting in a 3rd email address that I never use). I then went to my "work" stack overflow account to add my home gmail account as a login. I can't remember the exact order of things, but I started thinking things were strange when my work log's email address was my 3rd email address (the one I never use) instead of my work gmail account. Also the "about me" section said "please delete me".. which is what I had written in the "about me" section of my home stack overflow account (to delete it).

All my questions from both my home and work stack overflow accounts are now on this "merged" account. Logging on with my 3rd email address just fails - it does not recognize the address. However logging on using my home gmail account or work gmail account both log in to the same stack overflow profile. Also weird is under the previously used names, I have both my home and work names. However the user URL for my home account takes me to my work account, and the user URL for my work account seems to no longer exist (assuming I remember the numbers the right way around). What worries me is that I tagged my home account for deletion, and I'm worried that the instruction will now fall through to my work account! I'm also worried that things are tangled in such a way that I'm going to loose things down the line because parts of my account might now somehow be associated with an account that doesn't exist.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 3):

no worries. You edited your profile post-merge, so we'd have made double sure you really wanted It deleted before doing anything anyway.

The automatic merging behavior is intentional and will not cause any future problems with your account.